# Argument of \textbf has an extra }

Tags: fonts, errors, soul

I am writing the latex table code as follows:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|cc|cc|}
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{{\ul \textbf{One-vs-One parallel}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{{\ul \textbf{One-vs-All}}} \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p-value} & PCA & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p-value} & PCA \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{M1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{97\%} & 91.66\% & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{92.5\%} & 87.62\% \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{M2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{98.44\%} & 96.13\% & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{94\%} & 90.02\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison between p-value and PCA using one-vs-one parallel and one-vs-all for $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ motion}
\label{comparision}
\end{table}
```

It is giving an error

[image: Error]

Comment: Your code need `begin{document}` and `\end{document}`to be compiled.

Comment: we can not run your code but `\ul \textbf{xxx}`  is `\ul{\textbf}{xxx}`  I guess you wanted `\ul{\textbf{xxx}}`  this is unrelated to tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ul \textbf{xxx}` is `\ul{\textbf}{xxx}` I guess you wanted `\ul{\textbf{xxx}}`  `\ul` takes an argument (like `\textbf`) it is not a switch (like `\bfseries`) so you need braces around the text to underline.